# how can I change background color of dynamically filled table row based on the value of one of the cells?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table being filled dynamically from mysql database.  One of the columns in the table is a date.  I want to change the background color of the row if the date is more than 3 days old.  Trying to figure this out, I have figured out the formula and on a test.php page I can make it work with a textbox.  I need to know how to apply it to a table row.

```
function call_log_date($enter_date)
{
    $today      = strtotime(date("m/d/Y"));
    $other_date = strtotime($enter_date) . "<br>";
    // returns number of days between dates(because of abs, will always
    // return positive number)
    $diff = ceil(abs($today - $other_date) / (60 * 60 * 24));
    if ($diff > 3) {
        $bg_color   = "#FFFF00"; //yellow
        $font_color = "#FF0000"; //red
    } else if ($diff > 1 && $diff <= 3) {
        $bg_color   = "#FFFFFF"; // white
        $font_color = "#FF0000"; //red
    } else {
        $bg_color   = "#FFFFFF"; // white
        $font_color = "#000000"; //black
    }

    return $bg_color . $font_color;
}
```

Above is the function that I am using that works for a textbox

Comment: Euhm, just apply it to your table row in stead of your textbox? I think we're gonna need to see how you use this function, cause I don't get how an output like `"#FFFF00#FF0000"` can be applied to a textbox to start with...

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this (untested/undebugged):

**PHP:**

```
$tdclass = call_log_date($enter_date);
echo '<td class="' .$tdclass. '">' .$enter_date. '</td>';


function call_log_date($enter_date) {
    $today = strtotime(date("m/d/Y"));
    $other_date = strtotime($enter_date)."<br>";
    $diff =  ceil(abs($today - $other_date) / (60*60*24)); //returns number of days between dates(because of abs, will always return positive number)
    if($diff > 3) {
        return 'colorA';
    }else if($diff > 1 && $diff <= 3) {
        return 'colorB';
    }else {
        return 'colorC';
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.colorA{background-color:#FFFF00;color:#FF0000;}
.colorB{background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#FF0000;}
.colorC{background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how to put a color in a table row (CSS inline style):

```
<table>
    <tr style="background-color: #cc6600">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you are creating a table dynamically, just change that color with your function.